# Spark submit in IntelliJ of project jar yields Class not found error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, classnotfoundexception, intellij-14

I'm doing a basic program of implementing Drools and the program runs on an application configuration but when I try to run the JAR, I face an error.

The error I get on the terminal:

```
    `Suhita-MacBookPro:Drool-CreditScore-Sample sgoswami$ spark-submit --class main.scala.suhita.Sample --master local[*] target/DroolsMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.scala.suhita.Sample
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:712)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)`


Drools-Project
  >src
   >main
    >scala
     >suhita
      - Sample
      - Applicant
   >META-INF
    -kmodule.xml
    -manifest.MF
   >resources.rules
    -rules
```

Comment: A class is not found in the classpath. Who knows what is going on because you did not provide a [mcve]. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometime when your classes are not loaded property. I have seen a few times recently. So there are two ways to fix this issue:

- Refresh classes that may include `sbt clean compile`
- or you can try reloading idea classes from top menu. It's  very vague to say but sometimes restarting intellij  also works as it reloads all the classes again.

I am sure one the method will work. Let me know if it persists.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the *tree structure* of your project

```
Drools-Project
  >src
   >main
    >scala
     >suhita
      - Sample
      - Applicant
```

You don't need to provide *class name* from `main` as `main.scala.suhita.Sample`

Simply use `suhita.Simple` for *class name* as

```
spark-submit --class suhita.Sample --master local[*] target/DroolsMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and it should work